# How to call an anonymous module with webpack without require()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, commonjs

I have two files, `main.js` and `script.js`.

Using webpack, I want to make `MyLibrary` function available in `script.js`, so I can use it like this:

`main.js`:

```
function MyLibrary() {

    this.VERSION = '0.0.1';
    this.AUTHOR = 'John Smith';

    this.getAuthor = function() {

        return this.AUTHOR;

    };

    return this;

};

module.exports = new MyLibrary();
```

And `script.js`:

```
console.log( MyLibrary );
```

But this doesn't work.

Bear in mind, I don't want to use the `require()` function. I need this variable to be available inside `script.js`, but not in the global scope.

Here's my webpack config:

```
{
    entry: {
        main: 'main.js',
        script: 'script.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'compiled.js'
    }
}
```

Any ideas how can I achieve this?